# Crawler bot user agent format

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent

From what I can see, most popular bots user agent strings are following this format:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; <botname>/<botversion>; +<boturl>)`

What `compatible` means?

Why is there a plus(`+`) sign before bot info url?

Comment: You can copy a user-agent string from a browser, and override the user-agent string removing the default for bots.

Comment: @Danizavtz I know, but I don't want to fake a user. I want to know why common bots use this format.